# Error while adding Floating Action Button in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I add Floating action button from palette Error shows up something like this
"object is not an instance of declaring class"
"Exception raised during rendering: object is not an instance of declaring class (Details)"

I have tried to migrate to androidX still didnt work

This is my module level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vignesh.layoutlearn"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

I removed material design library,Now it works fine,but I want to know why it is like that.What if i need material design and fab?

Comment: Does it show up in the editor, or when you compile the project ?

Comment: It shows near Atrributes button with red icon thing. I removed material design library now it works fine,but why?

Comment: You removed material design library and you were able to use `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you go to **File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

If you're using the **support library** `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>
```

And if you're using the **AndroidX** version `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>
```

This should work..

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add this line to your dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

> It should be the same version of targeted SDK version.